# Pseudo previsão (Rolling)

Tags: r, estatística-bootstrap

Como fazer pseudo previsões fora da amostra, através de rolling regressions e com janela móvel contendo 50 observações, para t = 51 a 100? Uma das previsões deverá ser feita a partir de um AR(1). Outra será feita a partir de um passeio aleatório, ou seja, yt+1(estimado)=yt . Por fim, outra previsão será realizada utilizando-se os verdadeiros coeficientes:yt+1(estimado)=2+0,7yt  . Armazene as previsões de cada modelo em matrizes (ou vetores). Estimar o AR(1) através de MQO (lm(y~x)).

Uma previsão para o modelo com os verdadeiros coeficientes seria o seguinte, (Com mu=2 e phi=0.7, definidos previamente):

```
for (i in 1:R){
            y[i+1]=mu+phi*y[i]
}

reg=lm(y[i+1]~y[i])
```

Mas não estou conseguindo entender como incorporar esse modelo com os coeficientes verdadeiros na hora de fazer a rolling forecast, dado que ela regride as janelas de previsão (xt e xt1).

```
ar=1
for (i in 1:length(f)) {
            xt=window(x,start=c(year_start+i),end=c(year_start,R+i))
            xt1=window(x,start=c(year_start+i-1),end=c(year_start,R+i-1))
            for(p in 1:ar){xt1=cbind(xt1,lag(xt,-p))}
            y=na.omit(xt1)
            reg=lm(y[,1]~y[,2])
            cond.x=rev(tail(xt,ar))
            f[i]=reg$coefficients%*%c(1,cond.x)                                                     
            frw[i]=tail(xt,1)                                 
}
```

Tentei incluir o loop do modelo verdadeiro dentro do loop da rolling forecast, mas não está saindo.  Consegui fazer com um AR(1) qualquer, mas não incorporando os coeficientes verdadeiros. Alguém teria uma dica?